# Change Background Color of Clicked Child in ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I want to change the background color of the child which is clicked in an ExpandableListView. That is, when any child is clicked, it's background color should get changed.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return false;
            }
        });
```

** Edit **

```
final String selected = (String) yourAdapter.getChild(
                    groupPosition, childPosition);
```